# Will degreaser formula 88 harm your tire?

Tags: road-bike

I was using degreaser formula 88 and got some on my tire. I rinsed it off with some water and then the next day the tire had cracks and was faded. Will the tire get messed up ?

Comment: What is "degreaser 22"?

Comment: Degreaser formula 88 my mistake

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FORMULA 88 Material Safety Data Sheet](http://www.formula88.com/material_safety_data_sheet.pdf), this product is not dangerous, and is soluble in water. Washing it off was the best you could do.

My guess is that the solvent has dissolved some of the components of the tire rubber, leading to the fading and cracking you see. Only time will tell if the tire has been structurally compromised.

The most basic precaution would be to buy a new tire before this one fails.

You could continue to ride this one, if there are no signs of bulging from the internal pressure in the tube. But the *conservative* advice would be to replace it now.

Personally, I would put it on the back wheel and continue to ride on it, but keep it under observation. If the damaged area is smaller than a tube patch, I'd glue a patch on the inside. But if it starts to bulge, then I'd replace the tire promptly.

Comment: The safety data sheet indeed says (in section x) that this degreaser is incompatible with materials that are damaged ('dissolved') by strong acids or alkalies. Rubber materials are definitely in this area. It should also be a warning never to use baking soda or washing soda (sodium carbonate, an alkali) to wash bags or clothing made of rubber-coated textiles. (I once used washing soda to clean an old backpack. The coating on the backpack's inside just peeled off like dead skin.)

Comment: @TehMacDawg Good find! How about you add that as an answer?